# Multiple Contacts Per Lead - Possible?

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I need to find out if there is a way to have multiple people associated to a single lead. For instance, say your company interacts and sells to other businesses. For this scenario, say the sales team meets three people from the same company at an event. What would be the proper way to track all of this? It is possible to create three separate leads and then track activities on each of the leads, but how does the conversion process for those leads to accounts work over time?

Say, for instance, you have Joe, John, and Pam who are all executives for ABC Corporation. Your sales team meets them, gets their contact information, and enters all of their contact details into Salesforce as Leads. Over the course of a few weeks/months, the sales team interacts with each person and tracks that information as activities under their respective leads. Finally, after two months of conversation, Pam decides she is ready to do business. The sales team converts Pam and creates an account for ABC Corporation. We don't want to lose the contact info or the activity information associated with Joe and John, but correct me if I am wrong, if they are converted they will generate their own accounts. If they are not converted, we lose those interactions. How can we keep tracking all of that information while not creating duplicate data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When converting leads, you are prompted to add to an existing account or contact. After you convert the first one, you can attach to an existing Account.

[image]

Note, that I like using leads for only un-qualified leads. Once I have qualified them, I convert them to an Account of type Prospect and then create an opportunity that I start tracking.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it worked like that. Thanks!